# $a_1\textbf{v}_{1} + a_2\textbf{v}_{2} = b_1\textbf{v}_{1} + b_2\textbf{v}_{2} $ if and only if $a_1 = b_1$ and $a_2 = b_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Would it be correct to say that $a_1\textbf{v}_{1} + a_2\textbf{v}_{2} $ is equal to $b_1\textbf{v}_{1} + b_2\textbf{v}_{2} $ if and only if $a_1 = b_1$ and $a_2 = b_2$?

I feel as though it is a very silly question and i am quite ashamed to be asking it, but there is a doubt in my mind that it is true, that there may be some instance where it is not correct.

appologies in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if ${\bf v}_1$ and ${\bf v}_2$ are linearly independent. $$a_1{\bf v}_1 + a_2{\bf v}_2 = b_1{\bf v}_1+b_2{\bf v}_2 \implies (a_1-b_1){\bf v}_1+(a_2-b_2){\bf v_2} = 0,$$ and linear independence says that $a_1 - b_1 = a_2-b_2 = 0$, that is, $a_1=b_1$ and $a_2=b_2$.

(Don't be ashamed of asking. Don't be ashamed of learning.)

Answer (score 1):

Not at all silly.  It is correct if and only if ${\bf v}_1$ and ${\bf v}_2$ are linearly independent.